# Executing `ALTER TABLE my_table ENGINE InnoDB` on a MyISAM table has no effects. Why?

Tags: mysql, innodb, myisam, alter-table

I want to change a table from MyISAM to InnoDB. I executed

```
ALTER TABLE database_name.table_name ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

inside of the mysql shell in the terminal. There were no error reports. But

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE database_name.table_name;
```

shows me, that the table is still in MyISAM. What do I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is InnoDB enabled on your server? Run `SHOW ENGINES;` query to check.

Comment: The list `SHOW ENGINES` produced did not contain InnoDB. I remembered editing some InnoDB settings in `my.cnf` which obviously lead to this. Removing the settings and restarting the server let InnoDB appear in the list produced by `SHOW ENGINES` again. Thanks for the hint!